# Anybody what is the basic navigation, label, button, text box sizes in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I need to know about the basic sizes of the iPhone, iPad? So some one tell me about the basic matter of those machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. This contains the sizes of UI controls of iphone

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

You can also get more information here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UILabel-SW1

Also

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/